# FB sdk causes Jar mismatch

Tags: android, android-facebook

I added FB 3.7 sdk project refrence to my project,

Now i get the error:

```
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at     this time).
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant] Versions found are:
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\מיכאל\Personal Assistant\Jars\facebook-   android-sdk-3.7\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant]     Length: 621451
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\AndroidWorkspace\MyAssistant\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant]     Length: 385685
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2014-02-28 10:47:48 - MyAssistant] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant] Versions found are:
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\מיכאל\Personal Assistant\Jars\facebook-   android-sdk-3.7\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant]     Length: 621451
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\AndroidWorkspace\MyAssistant\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant]     Length: 385685
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2014-02-28 10:47:52 - MyAssistant] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant] Versions found are:
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\מיכאל\Personal Assistant\Jars\facebook-android-sdk-3.7\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant]     Length: 621451
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\AndroidWorkspace\MyAssistant\libs\android-support-v4.jar    
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant]     Length: 385685
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e 
[2014-02-28 10:47:53 - MyAssistant] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time). 
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant] Versions found are:
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\מיכאל\Personal Assistant\Jars\facebook- android-sdk-3.7\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant]     Length: 621451
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\AndroidWorkspace\MyAssistant\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant]     Length: 385685
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2014-02-28 10:48:33 - MyAssistant] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant] Versions found are:
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\מיכאל\Personal Assistant\Jars\facebook-android-sdk-3.7\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant]     Length: 621451
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant] Path: C:\AndroidWorkspace\MyAssistant\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant]     Length: 385685
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant]     SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2014-02-28 10:48:42 - MyAssistant] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

It seems like support package V4 is mismatching. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please copy the jar file from your project to facebook sdk library and clean it. You have to use same jar for all your library projects and application projects. Because any library from github or any community will come with old andoird-support-v4.jar, better you replace all library project's support-v4.jar with your application project's support-v4.jar.

Then if you get any exclamation mark like please goto properties->javabuildpath->orderandexport select all checkboxes and remove the missing one...

I hope it will help you............

Answer (score 2):

I too had a same problem few day's back.

**Solution**.

1) Remove android support v4.jar from your main project.

2) Then right click your project and goto Properties and select **JavaBuildPath**

3) goto **Libraries** tab and click on Add External jars

4) Browse jar files and add jar files from your Facebook Library project that is `facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0 -> facebook -> libs`

4) add it and then goto **order and export** tab next to **Libraries** and there you will see android support v4 jar, check on it and press apply and Ok.

That's it, clean your project and try to run your project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the updated support library from the android sdk manager. Mismatch happening bcoz of different versions of the jar.

Then copy the `android_support-v4.jar` to the libs folder of both your project and the facebook library project.

The support library can be found under the following path

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android_support-v4.jar
```